# Почему не срабатывает селектор

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<label class="label_check d-flex align-items-center"><input type="checkbox" class="me-2"><span class="me-2"></span>Ноутбук</label>

label.label_check:has(> input[type="checkbox"]:checked){
color: #34a0c7;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

[:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

> /* Note that this is not supported in any browser yet */

что означает

> /* Учтите, что это пока не поддерживается ни одним браузером */

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]